# Linear Algebra Linear Independence Proof

Tags: linear-algebra

How would I prove the following?

$V$ is a vector space and $S$ a subset of $V$ containing at least $2$ elements. Then $S$ is linearly independent iff no elements of $S$ can be written as a linear combination of the remaining elements of $S$.

I know linearly independent means that all coefficients $a_i$ in field $\mathbb{F}$ equal $0$, but I'm not sure how or if this is used for this proof.

Comment: Prove it by contradiction.

Comment: you knows what is a linear combination? Check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_combination) and compare with the definition of linear independence.

Comment: @saulspatz so would I prove it is linearly dependent? and what would my contradiction be

Comment: To do it by contradiction, you start by assuming that some vector can be expressed as a linear combination of the others.  Now compare that to the definition of linear independence.  The contradiction wii be clear to you, I think.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* The easiest route is to use the contrapositive:

> $S$ is linearly dependent iff some element of $S$ can be written as a linear combination of the remaining elements of $S$.

Comment: So, I prove the statement true (in both directions) and that is the contradiction?

Comment: @Liza, contrapositive, not contradiction. Just note that $P \iff Q$ is equivalent to $\neg P \iff \neg Q$.

Comment: Oh, ok. Also, I know how to prove the first direction, but how would I prove the other direction of the above statement? Wouldn't it imply that the vectors could be linearly dependent OR independent if they form  a linear combination?